# How to add initial admin using script in Keycloak.X Quarkus Preview?

Tags: keycloak

The Wildfly version provies an add-user-keycloak script under bin folder using which we can create initial admin account. How can I do the same with the Quarkus Preview version?

Comment: Apparently it's not currently possible: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-community/issues/176#issuecomment-696533843

Answer (score 1):

Use the following environment variables after which you can run the server

> export KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=`username`
> export KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=`password`
>
> bin/kc.[sh|bat] start

The documentation [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#creating-the-account-remotely) can help as well

Answer (score 0):

Adding default admin by environment variable is working only if the USER_ENTITY table is empty.